# Where to get versions suitability sheet of neat and bourbon?

Tags: sass, rubygems, bourbon

I want so use libsass for compiling my scss (considering positive testimonials about it's speed against ruby native compiler). The compiling ends with an error, and my searching have driven me here: (my bourbon was 4.x): https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/365. the current version of libsass cannot compile bourbon 4.x. and the issue is closed. Okay, lets install bourbon 3.x.

> gem install bourbon -v 3

and then

> gem install neat

and the damn thing installs the latest neat (1.7.x) and bourbon 4.x as a dependency for it (along with already installed bourbon 3.x). I cannot make it install neat precisely for bourbon 3.x, and I couldn't ever find any info about which neat version is compatible with bourbon 3.x. Not on bourbon.io, not on github.com, not on stackoverflow.com, not anywhere... Maybe it's just a matter of SASS version, but why gem installs the latest bourbon then? If there is already one in the system? Or maybe there is any gem option exists which tells gem to lower the version of requested package, if dependent packages versions indicate so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compatibility issues that Bourbon had with Libsass got sorted out quite some time ago, and that thread is from last year.

Do you mind posting your compiling error?

If you try to install a gem without a version, it will grab the newest one, so you would want to install a version of Neat that required a 3.x version of Bourbon. I don't think that should be necessary though if we can solve your compiling problem. Those commands also install the gems to your local system, rather than in your project directory, so you will want to use a Gemfile (for Ruby projects) or something like package.json (for npm projects).

Comment: That is awesome news! Thank you! Now everything is cool! I've downloaded the latest libsass, did all the stuff, tried many wrappers, and finally managed to compile and make it run with sassc. Now everything runs fine without errors. In previous libsass it was "unexpected eof" error in some of bourbon files. Now the speed is excellent! With libsass and bourbon/neat, LiveReload, and two 1920x1080 monitors... It's a new level of markup design speed and handy-ness! Amazing! :-)